# How remove the space at the end from the enum value defined in proto file in grpc?

Tags: go, enums, protocol-buffers, grpc

I have a `Message` in a proto file as below where it also includes an `enum`.

```
message ServiceTechnology {
    enum Technology {
        GPU = 0;
        CPU = 1;
        TK_CPU = 2;
        TK_GPU = 3;
    }
    Technology technology = 1;
}
```

I've 2 questions here. When I try to use one of the enum values here, I get the following output `technology:<technology:TK_GPU >` there's a space at the end. THis is the minor problem. However, I don't even want to get the output like that. I want the value only. Not like that `technology:<technology:TK_GPU >`  but like that `technology: TK_GPU`, so when I extract the value I will only collect the value itself which is TK_GPU here.

This is how I'm using this message in another message.

```
message Temporary {
  ServiceTechnology technology = 1;
}
```

and when I try to set this in the code I'm doing it as below:

```
Technology: &ServiceTechnology{Technology: ServiceTechnology_TK_GPU},
```

I guess I have to add the extra field called `Technology` here in the message `ServiceTechnology`, as much as I know, otherwise is not acceptable. So, how should get rid of extra information but just get the enum value itself?

Comment: How do you get the output `technology:<technology:TK_GPU >`?

Comment: The `protoc-go-gen` plugin creates two helper maps that map between the string values e.g. `TK_GPU` and the integer `3`. You can `pb.ServiceTechnology_Technology_value["TK_GPU"]` and `pb.ServiceTechnology_Technology_name[3]`

Comment: The only alternative to the way the `enum` is generated is if you pull it out of the message definition and make it a type that's available across the package. Then, instead of `pb.ServiceTechnology_TK_GPU` you could e.g. use `pb.Technology_TK_GPU`.